# Results Viewer Not Displaying Title in Proc Means

Tags: sas

I recently switched computers at work and now when I output the results of procedures such as proc means, the data looks like plain text and it has weird behavior. I'm using SAS 9.3.

For instance, it won't display the title I defined and it doesn't clearly mark the results for the different values of the by variable.

Has anyone ever run across this? I have gone into preferences and ods graphics/enable html are checked.

Comment: Are you using SAS Enterprise Guide or SAS Windowing Environment?

Comment: SAS Windowing Environment

Comment: Try change `ods style`
Tools->Options->Preferences->Results->Style
In default is HTMLBlue (SAS 9.4)

Comment: What tab are you looking at?  `Output` or `Results`?

Comment: @Joe I'm using results viewer

Comment: @Robert S Thanks. I've tried a few but it's always the same. the background and font changes slightly but still getting the same basic problems. Here is a screenshot I took of 4 different styles: http://imgur.com/a/hGm4M

Comment: It's a listing result, but should be a html result, check the same tab (Tools->Options->Preferences->Results). Uncheck listing and check html.

Comment: Listing results shouldn't be viewable in Results Viewer though, as far as I know?

Comment: @confusedCat If Robert's suggestion in the answer doesn't help you, you may want to post a screenshot to show what exactly you mean (open a new SAS session, run `title 'mytitle'; proc means data=sashelp.class; run; title;` or something, then screenshot what you're seeing that you don't like).

Comment: You should contact tech support. If this is a clean install they should be made aware of the issue, and they respond quickly though I think you may have missed their hours now for the weekend.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I posted a screenshot to the results viewer output I'm getting. My code is this:

title 'hi';
PROC MEANS DATA=delinquent N MIN MAX MEAN STD NMISS;
 BY limlt10k;
 VAR n_currutil;
RUN;

Comment: I don't see your screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Preferences->Results

[image: Results tab]

Comment: Thanks. Just for posterity I want to clarify that the "Create listing" option is unchecked. When I check it, I get a listing output in the "output" window and it does show the title properly.